# Centering widgets in Tkinter frame using .pack()

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

I'm trying to get all of my labels and input boxes to be shifted down to the middle of the screen using the .pack() method. I tried using

```
anchor = CENTER
```

with the.place() method but that made everything overlap in the center. How can I simply shift all of my widgets to the center of my Tkinter frame?

Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.minsize(width = 500, height = 500)
root.wm_title("Email Program v1.0")

def callback():
    print ("Hello!")

#sign in - email
usernameLabel = Label(root, text = "Email:")
usernameLabel.pack(padx = 0, pady = 0)

usernameInput = Entry(root)
usernameInput.pack()
usernameInput.focus_set()

passwordLabel = Label(root, text = "Password:")
passwordLabel.pack()

passwordInput = Entry(root, show = "*", width = 20)
passwordInput.pack()
passwordInput.focus_set()

#submit email credentials - connect to the server
submitEmail = Button(root, text = "Submit", fg = "black", width = 10, command = callback)
submitEmail.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How can you expect them all to be centered and yet not overlap?  If two things are centered, they by definition will be on top of each other.

Comment: This code, with pack(anchor="center") works on my machine.  Some further code/explanation is required to duplicate the problem.

Comment: To the center just horizontally or also vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to put all the widgets in a frame, and then center the frame.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to put those labels and entries to the center using three frames, two without any content just to 'eat' space.

```
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack(expand=True)

frame2 = Frame(root)

usernameLabel = Label(frame2, text = "Email:")
usernameLabel.pack(padx = 0, pady = 0)

usernameInput = Entry(frame2)
usernameInput.pack()
usernameInput.focus_set()

passwordLabel = Label(frame2, text = "Password:")
passwordLabel.pack()

passwordInput = Entry(frame2, show = "*", width = 20)
passwordInput.pack()
passwordInput.focus_set()
submitEmail = Button(frame2, text = "Submit", fg = "black", width = 10, command\
 = callback)
submitEmail.pack()

frame2.pack(anchor=CENTER)

frame3 = Frame(root)
frame3.pack(expand=True)
```